# How to rewrite "where, and, or" statement from this ugly code

Tags: sql, t-sql

my code works but is awful. is there a way to clean this code in an proper way?

this code (stored proc) is used to do a search for a word in different columns in one table and posts that have different roll id (0-4)

```
@searchval nvarchar(500),
@arrStatusTyp int,
@rolltypAdmin int,
@roll1 int,
@roll2 int,
@roll3 int,
@roll4 int,
@visningsperiod nvarchar(4)

SELECT  kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrID    
    FROM    kk_aj_tbl_content INNER JOIN
                kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent ON kk_aj_tbl_content.Contentid = kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.contentid INNER JOIN
                kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang ON kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.arrid = kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrID INNER JOIN
                kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrangemangStatusID = kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus.ArrangemangStatusID INNER JOIN
                kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.KonstformID = kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID INNER JOIN
                Users ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.AdminuserID = Users.UserID INNER JOIN
                kk_aj_tbl_utovare ON kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.UtovarID = kk_aj_tbl_utovare.UtovarID
    WHERE  
        (kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrangemangStatusID = @arrStatusTyp) AND (kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.Version=1) AND 
        (
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%') AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll1) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%') AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll2) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%') AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll3) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%') AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll4) OR                 
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Underrubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll1) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Underrubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll2) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Underrubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll3) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_content.Underrubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll4) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_utovare.Organisation LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll1) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_utovare.Organisation LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll2) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_utovare.Organisation LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll3) OR
            (kk_aj_tbl_utovare.Organisation LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%')AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID = @roll4) 
        )
    ORDER BY kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.datum DESC
```

thanks for all help

Comment: Why don't you use `(kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%') AND (kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID in (@roll1,@roll2,@roll3,@roll4)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions like :

```
(cond1 OR cond2)
AND (cond1 OR cond3)
AND (cond1 OR cond4)
...
```

Can be rewritten as :

```
cond1 AND (cond2 OR cond3 OR cond4)
```

Hence try the following `WHERE` clause :

```
...
WHERE  
kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang.ArrangemangStatusID = @arrStatusTyp
AND kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent.Version=1
AND kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp.KonstformID IN (@roll1, @roll2, @roll3, @roll4)           
AND ( 
    kk_aj_tbl_content.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%'
    OR kk_aj_tbl_content.Underrubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%'
    OR kk_aj_tbl_content.Organisation LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%'
)
```

Comment: Good one !!! This also may fix a performance problem as OR clause in the WHERE may cause severe performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

First use a custom table alias so you don't have to repeat the full table name (use a significant one, not A, B, C like my example). You can rewrite your multiple `OR` as `IN`:

```
WHERE  
    A.ArrangemangStatusID = @arrStatusTyp AND 
    D.Version = 1 AND 
    (
        (B.Rubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' AND E.KonstformID IN (@roll1, @roll2, @roll3, @roll4)) OR
        (B.Underrubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' AND E.KonstformID IN (@roll1, @roll2, @roll3, @roll4)) OR
        (C.Organisation LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' AND E.KonstformID IN (@roll1, @roll2, @roll3, @roll4))
    )
```

You don't need to enclose all conditions in parenthesis, only use them when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.arrid 
  FROM kk_aj_tbl_content 
       INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_arridtocontent 
               ON kk_aj_tbl_content.contentid = kk_aj_tbl_arridtocontent.contentid 
       INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang 
               ON kk_aj_tbl_arridtocontent.arrid = kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.arrid 
       INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_arrangemangstatus 
               ON kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.arrangemangstatusid = kk_aj_tbl_arrangemangstatus.arrangemangstatusid
       INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp 
               ON kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.konstformid = kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.adminuserid = users.userid 
       INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_utovare 
               ON kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.utovarid = kk_aj_tbl_utovare.utovarid 
 WHERE ( kk_aj_tbl_arrangemang.arrangemangstatusid = @arrStatusTyp ) 
   AND ( kk_aj_tbl_arridtocontent.version = 1 ) 
   AND ( ( kk_aj_tbl_content.rubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
         AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll1 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.rubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll2 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.rubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll3 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.rubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll4 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.underrubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll1 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.underrubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll2 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.underrubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll3 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_content.underrubrik LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll4 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_utovare.organisation LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll1 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_utovare.organisation LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll2 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_utovare.organisation LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll3 ) 
          OR ( kk_aj_tbl_utovare.organisation LIKE '%' + @searchval + '%' ) 
             AND ( kk_aj_tbl_konstformtyp.konstformid = @roll4 ) ) 
 ORDER BY kk_aj_tbl_arridtocontent.datum DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using table alias and simplifying WHERE clause:

```
SELECT  am.ArrID    
FROM    kk_aj_tbl_content c
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_arridtoContent a2c     ON  c.Contentid     = a2c.contentid
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_Arrangemang am         ON  a2c.arrid   = am.ArrID 
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_ArrangemangStatus ams  ON am.ArrangemangStatusID = ams.ArrangemangStatusID 
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_Konstformtyp kft       ON am.KonstformID = kft.KonstformID 
INNER JOIN Users u                          ON am.AdminuserID = u.UserID 
INNER JOIN kk_aj_tbl_utovare uto            ON am.UtovarID = uto.UtovarID
WHERE am.ArrangemangStatusID = @arrStatusTyp
AND a2c.Version = 1 
AND kft.KonstformID in (@roll1,@roll2,@roll3,@roll4)
AND (
            c.Rubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%'        OR
            c.Underrubrik LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%'   OR
            uto.Organisation LIKE '%'+@searchval+'%'
)
ORDER BY a2c.datum DESC
```